# In 4.7 CiviCase relationships are being inserted the wrong way round: bug or feature?

Tags: civicase, issues

On the 4.7 Drupal demo site I created a case of type 'Housing Support' for Rebekah Adams. I added Beulah Barkley as the 'Benefits Specialist. My user (Test Test in the demo) was the 'Homeless Service Coordinator'.

The problem is that the 2 relationships get added differently.

[image: Relationships for Rebekah Adams]

The image shows the relationships tab from Rebekah Adams' record (the case client). Note that Test Test is her Homeless Services Coordinator (OK), while she is the Benefits Specialist for Beula Barkley (Ouch, wrong way around).

Both relationships are defined the same way (B->A notation) in the Case definition ...

[image]

This is clearly a bug as it used to work fine in 4.6.

Comment: This seems to be due to CRM-16980 - Improve case role handing. The code seems to now expect the client to be Contact B in the relationship. Except for the Case Manager relationship where the client is Contact A!

Comment: Has this been logged as a bug?